# Extracting CDATA Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, cdata

It looks like this has been asked before, but the answers do not appear to work for me.  I am outputting information from a local XML file, but the description elements is not being output because it is enclosed in CDATA - if I remove the CDATA portion then things work fine.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $.get('test.xml',
      function($info) {
        objInfo = $($info);

        objInfo.find('item').slice(0,5).each(
          function() {
            var Guid = $(this).find('guid').text();
            var Title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var Description = $(this).find('description').text();
            $('#Content').append(
              "<p><a href='" + Guid + "'>" + 
              Title + "</a>&nbsp;" +
              Description +
              "</p>"
            )
          }
        );

      },
      'xml'
    );
  }
)
```

Any idea how I can successfully extract Description information that is wrapped in CDATA?

Thanks -

george

Comment: can you provide the portion of xml code!?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent the last few hours on something very similar, and what worked for me was explicitly setting the content type to "text/xml" and "xml" on sending / receiving sides.  I.e,

Server side:

```
...
response.setContentType("text/xml");
...
```

Client / jQuery side:

```
... 
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'myAjaxHandler',
  processData: false,
  data: message,
  contentType: 'text/xml', 
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(xml, textStatus) {
   var myVar= $(xml).find('interestingNode').text();
   $('#someId').append(myVar); 
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   ...
  }
 });

...
```

Not sure if both are required.

From the documentation, if you don't specify the content type anywhere, jQuery will try to "guess" what you are sending, and in my case I had HTML embedded in CDATA.